# Multiple thumbnails in checkout section on woocommerce/fancy product designer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

In my Woocommerce website users can design their own up to 6 different images via [Fancy product designer](https://fancyproductdesigner.com/) plugin. I'm trying to output those users thumbnails on cart items in checkout page instead of just showing one product image.

[Website](https://www.invitationer-til-fest.dk/produkt/elegant-delux-invitation-bryllup-nr-6-design-selv/) I'm trying to make this possible.

[image] (example photo)

---

**class-wc-cart.php**

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML( $thumbnail );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
libxml_clear_errors();

$doc = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(1);
$src = $xpath->query(".//@src");
$srcset = $xpath->query(".//@srcset");

// custom image from customer 
foreach ( $src as $s ) {
    $s->nodeValue = $fpd_data['fpd_product_thumbnail'];
}
foreach ( $srcset as $s ) {
    $s->nodeValue = $fpd_data['fpd_product_thumbnail'];
}
return $dom->saveXML( $doc );
```

I use a foreach to loop through the images from fancy product designer. But it's like it's just lists the first image in my checkout.

Any idea if it's even possible or I should use another approach in the `class-wc-cart.php` file in woocommerce.

---

**class-wc-product.php**

```
//the additional form fields
public function add_product_designer_form() {

        global $post;
        $product_settings = new FPD_Product_Settings($post->ID);

        if( $product_settings->show_designer() ) {
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" name="add-to-cart" />
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="fpd_product" />
            <input type="hidden" value="" name="fpd_product_thumbnail[]" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['cart_item_key']) ? $_GET['cart_item_key'] : ''; ?>" name="fpd_remove_cart_item" />
            <?php

            if( !fpd_get_option('fpd_wc_disable_price_calculation') )
                echo '<input type="hidden" value="" name="fpd_product_price" />';

            do_action('fpd_product_designer_form_end', $product_settings);
        }
}
```

In the code there is a function "**after_product_designer**" where I add some jquery code to get the input field that is supposed to post multiple fpd_thumbnails from FPD.

It's in **if(order.product != false)**

```
    var values = [];

if(<?php echo fpd_get_option('fpd_cart_custom_product_thumbnail'); ?>) {
    // $cartForm.find('input[name="fpd_product_thumbnail"]').val(dataURL); (OLD/Original)

    $('input[name="fpd_product_thumbnail[]"]').each(function(){ // NEW 
     values.push($(this).val(dataURL));
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having? If you're just trying to find out *how* can you display the multiple thumbnails, then you can use the `woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail` filter, or use a custom `cart.php` template and edit the [appropriate section](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.5.4/templates/cart/cart.php#L62).

Comment: The Thing is that I don't know how to loop through all the thumbnails that the user create via. Fancy Product Designer. I'm already using a very similar example from the link you refer from.

Comment: Fancy Product Designer is a premium plugin. Have you already tried contacting their support?

Comment: Yes, just did it a couple of hours ago.

Comment: In your code here `$doc = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img")->item(1);` looks like you're selecting only one image. You can loop through all items. Check out examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php Also, could you provide, what html is inside `$thumbnail` and what `$fpd_data` does contain?

Comment: There are a couple of problems in your code. One thing I notice is that you are looping over `$src` and assigning `$fpd_data['fpd_product_thumbnail']` to each variable. But you are assigning it to a copy of the original that `foreach` creates. If you want to preserve changes you should use the reference operator (&). Like this: `foreach ($src as &$s)`

Comment: @Dmitry  I just edited my post with the code I'm using. $fpd_data contains all the product information in one single json_encode which is saved in the database woocommerce_sessions. Here are the fpd_product_thumbnail also saved. But only 1 image - which is a problem if a customer add 5-6 other images that needs to be saved in the DB.

Comment: @SallyCJ FPD are not willing to help: Here is a anwser from them: Your support licence has expired. Even if you extend it (via your envato account) I'm afraid I can not promise that we will/ can help with your problem as it is custom development.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that @william. They could've at least pointed you to the proper documentation, or pinpointed you to a guide or resources that could help you. Nonetheless, I'm glad you found a solution, and +1 for it (or your efforts..) and the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to extract base64 images from fancy product designer and list in my checkout. Somehow they are all combined in one vertical base64 file. Haven't found a solution for that yet. But this is not related for this topic.

Change: 
**class-wc-product.php** and change `fancyProductDesigner.viewInstances[0].toDataURL` to `fancyProductDesigner.getProductDataURL` This creates all views in one data URL. The different views will be positioned below each other as mention in FPD jquery [documentation](https://jquerydoc.fancyproductdesigner.com/classes/FancyProductDesigner.html#method_getProductDataURL).

Change:
**class-wc-order.php** function add_order_item_meta to below code.

```
public function add_order_item_meta( $item_id, $item ) {

        $fpd_data = null;
        if( isset( $item->legacy_values['_fpd_data'] ) )  // WC 3.0+
            $fpd_data = $item->legacy_values['_fpd_data'];
        else if( isset( $item['_fpd_data'] ) )  // WC <3.0
            $fpd_data = $item['_fpd_data'];

        if( !is_null($fpd_data) ) {
            wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_fpd_data', $fpd_data);
        }
    }
```

That's my solution.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should have asked WP-related questions to [WP.SE](https://s.tk/wp)

2) Your solution should be below code (add in `functions.php` and modify per your needs):

```
// Product thumbnail in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', 'product_thumbnail_in_checkout', 200, 3 );
function product_thumbnail_in_checkout( $thumbnail, $cart_item, $cart_item_key )
{
    $use_product_thumb = false;   //true or false
    if (array_key_exists('fpd_data', $cart_item))
    {
        $thumbnail =""; //clear existing thumb
        if ($use_product_thumb)
        {
            $fp = json_decode( stripslashes($cart_item['fpd_data']['fpd_product']) , true);
            foreach($fp['product'] as $each)
            {
             $thumb = $each["thumbnail"];
             $thumbnail .= '<img src="'.$thumb.'" style="width:50px; float:left; margin:5px;" />';
            }
        }
        else{
            $thumbnail = '<img src="'.$cart_item['fpd_data']['fpd_product_thumbnail'].'" style="float: left; margin: 5px; width: 200px; max-width: 550px;" />'; 
        }
    }
    return $thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that this output my thumbnail previews for the product. I want to output the thumbnails that are generated via. fancy product designer which is currently saved as base64 images somewhere in their system - And I can't seem to solve how and where I can exstract thoose images.

Comment: @william I've updated answer. that shows thumbnails, however (it's the plugin cause) if the thumbnails are small , you should just zoom it with styling to make a bit bigger.  You cant increase their quality, the plugin has that problem as i see.

Comment: Sorry but related plugins questions are off topic on WP.SE, so StackOverFlow is the right place for Woocommerce questions and related plugins!